# Is there a command to check an array for a certain value?

Tags: java, arrays, boolean

So I am writing a game for fun with my friend and it includes a few boolean arrays. This isn't exactly how it is, but it is along these lines.
Boolean Array Example:

```
 boolean resultA = didWin(new boolean[]{true, false, true, true});
```

Pretty much I need a line of code that can check resultA to see if there is a false in it (or true).
I am pretty sure I read about it somewhere that it did exist but I am not entirely sure.

didWin is another method

Comment: Why don't you use `List` instead of Array? `ArrayList` is a good implementation, is backed by an array, and you have all operations that you need.

Answer (score 3):

There is no out of the box way, you have three solutions:

- `Arrays.asList(array).contains(Boolean.FALSE)`, convert it to a list backed by the array (doesn't work in your case since you are working with a primitive type boolean, you would need it's boxed counterpart)
- `for (boolean b : array) if (!b) return true`, iterate over the array
- `ArrayUtils.contains(array, false)` from [apache commons](http://commons.apache.org/), which gives you the utility

Comment: `Arrays.asList` does not work with `boolean[]`. It can only wrap `Object` arrays.